# Message broadcast with multiple receivers

Tags: c#, tcp, udp, message, msmq

I have a mainform that sends messages and a random number of receive forms that run as separate application (C# 4.0).

Everytime one of the random number of forms receive's the message but than the message is received and the others won't receive it anymore.

I've tried this with UDP, TCP IP, MSMQ but I don't seem to get it working well. The sender and receivers run on the same system.

Can anyone recommend me a way to broadcast a message that stays in a sort of queue till all the forms have received it, or maybe it can stay in that queue till the application closes, but how...?

Thanks in advance people!

Kind regards
Wesley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messaging pattern you are looking for is called [publish-subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish_subscribe). MSMQ does not support this messaging pattern natively.

However there are a number of open source tools which do including [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html) and [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/).

Comment: Am I wrong if I suggest the use of Multicast addresses with MSMQ?

Comment: @MykaEyl - hey, if you know a way of doing multicast with msmq please post it! That's beyond my understanding

Comment: @TomRedfern Sure, I have posted one answer.

Answer (score 6):

### Multicast MSMQ

You can use **MSMQ with Multicast** option (check that your Windows installation has that option before trying it, you will find it in the "add/remove windows features" section of the Windows control panel).

A sender using the MSMQ Multicast Queue will submit a message that can be processed by many MSMQ Multicast Queue receivers.

### Receiver

The reader must have a private queue, then you will need to set the multicast address that you want to use (the choice of the multicast address is arbitrary, that's why you will often see the same address mentionned in different posts, see the msdn docs for more information), like this:

```
var myQueue = MessageQueue.Create(".\private$\MulticastTest", false);
myQueue.MulticastAddress = "234.1.1.1:8001";
```

or directly use the existing multicast queue (if it has been created with the multicast address) the standard way:

```
var myQueue = new MessageQueue(multicastQueueName());
```

Then you will have to listen for new messages using your prefered method, I prefer to use this one:

```
myQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(String) });
myQueue.PeekCompleted += new PeekCompletedEventHandler(QueuePeekCompleted);
myQueue.BeginPeek();
```

The delegate QueuePeekCompleted looks like this:

```
     private void QueuePeekCompleted(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e)
     {
        try
        {
            var message = myQueue.EndPeek(e.AsyncResult);

            //LogInfo("Received this : " + message.Body);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LogError(ex);
        }
        myQueue.Receive();
        myQueue.BeginPeek();
    }
```

### Sender

The sender of a multicast message must connect to the multicast queue like this:

```
MessageQueue myQueue = new MessageQueue("formatname:multicast=234.1.1.1:8001");
```

Then send a message as usual:

```
myQueue.Send("hey listen!");
```

Comment: How to change it make it work when publishers and subscribers are on different computers??

Comment: Well its not a problem, the only limitation is one server to hold the queue (because msmq is a centralized queue), but there is no limitation on which one listens or publish messages. I did my tests on different computers.